# Maximum Altitude/Minimum Range limits of ATC PSR

Tags: air-traffic-control, radar

I am trying to get an understanding of the ability of an air traffic control primary radar such as an ATCR-33 to track high flying targets (above 40,000 feet) at relatively close ranges (less than 15 nm horizontal distance from the radar).  An alternative way of asking the question is what is the maximum 'beam elevation' (I think that that is the correct term) for a radar like an ATCR-33?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20180426140905/http://radarlab.uniroma2.it/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Seminario-su-ATCR-33S-2008-Protopapa.pdf) seems to show beam elevation from 0 to 40 degrees, dropping off after that.

See slides 10 and 15.

Comment: Thank you very much for that presentation, that's enormously helpful.